# Create copy of existing table with indexes, constraints and structure but without data

Tags: sql, postgresql, create-table, alter-table, bigint

Problem statement : in a postgresql table I am getting an error as "Integer out of range" for the column 'id' type 'serial integer'

RCA : As it is a serial integer column which already exceeded its maximum range of 2147483647. And it is unable to load more data

Solution : Need to change the datatype of the column from INTEGER to BIGINT.

for this solution I tried to execute the ALTER command
ALTER TABLE table_name ALTER COLUMN id TYPE BIGINT
But the table consists of more than 2 billion data, it is taking time also ALTER command creating some duplicate tables internally which is consuming all the space in the DB.

As a alternative method we are trying different workaround
that is to create a copy of the table with id column as BIGINT instead of INTEGER. Then move the data from old table to new table

**QUESTION: How to create a new copy table with same Table definition/structure, indexes and constraints but without data?
OR any other possible ways to solve my problem of 'Integer_out_of_range'**

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [LIKE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtable.html) and INCLUDING:

```
CREATE TABLE new_table(LIKE current_table INCLUDING ALL);
```